# How to implement a usergroup to hostgroup permission (using laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, relationships

I'm migrating an app to Laravel 5. My app deals with SSH accesses to hosts.

On one hand, I've got a `users` table where I put SSH user's keys, this users are grouped using `usergroups` table.

In the other hand I've got a `hosts` table, and I group hosts using `hostgroups` table.

Until here I've got 4 models: `User`, `Usergroups`, `Host` and `Hostgroup`.

`User` and `Usergroup` has a Many-to-Many relationship.
`Host` and `Hostgroup` has a Many-to-Many relationship.

My app implements some permissions, making a group of users can o can't access to a group of hosts. In my **old app**, I was using a `usergroup_hostgroup_permission` table.

```
Table: usergroup_hostgroup_permission
------------------------------
id
usergroup_id
hostgroup_id
permission (allow or deny)
description
enabled (boolean)
```

But, I'm not sure if it should be a model, or a relationship...

Can you help me to implement this?

Thanks in advance.
Paco